# In Mvc,I cant getting values from JSON object

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I cant any value from json.Values come 'null'.Where is the problem?

MY:JQUERY CODE IN siparis.cshtml

```
var array_table = [];
array_table.push({
  arrayName: "Name Value",
  arrayMail: "Mail Value",
  arrayMobile: "mobile Value"
});
}

$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("SiparisOlustur")', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify( array_table),
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
    $('#POCStatus').html('<div class="success">POC Removed Successfully.</div>');
  },
  error: function () {
    $('#POCStatus').html('<div class="field-validation-error">Some Error Occured in Removing POC.</div>');
  }
});
```

My JSON Model:

```
public class JsonModel
{
    public string arrayName { get; set; }
    public string arrayMail { get; set; }
    public string arrayMobile { get; set; }
}
```

My SiparisController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SiparisOlustur(List<JsonModel> array_table)
{
  return View();
}
```

Result is this:

ARRAY_TABLE IS COMING NULL

Thank You,
Regards,
B.Y.

Answer (score 0):

Give `array_table` name in data in ajax call as :

```
data: {array_table : JSON.stringify( array_table)}
```